# how do i create a link to open a website in new tab at java (netbeans)

Tags: java, html, gwt, netbeans, tabs

```
         linkPanel.setVisible(true);            
         String belgelerInnerHTML = "";
         belgelerInnerHTML = belgelerInnerHTML + "<p><a href=\"http://.."> click here </a></p>";
         linkPanel.setHtml(belgelerInnerHTML);
```

Basically i have this link, in my java project. But when i click the link it opens the website in same page.

I want it to open the website in new window or in new tab?

I thought maybe i can set a property to linkPanel to laways open links in new tab or there should be a code like OpenNewWindow (like ASP) but i couldn't find a solution. So please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
belgelerInnerHTML = belgelerInnerHTML + "<p><a href='http://..' target='_blank'> click here </a></p>";
```

This will open your link in new-tab.

Comment: shouldn't we use "" instead of '' in html. (or it doesn't matter)?

Comment: we can use `"string"` instead of `'string'`, here we can use it like `"<p><a href=\"http://..\" target=\"_blank\">..."`...